# Setting lat/lon coordinate pairs to main dataset index

Tags: python, coordinates, gis

I am essentially taking GOES satellite data (which has xy coordinates) and calculating lat/lons with the code below. I break it down into a dataframe and then an xarray data array to do operations on it. The code I currently have assigns lat/lons as a coordinate pair to the dataset, which as a pair cannot be set as the dataset index (but it needs to be the index to be retained when it is broken down into an xarray data array).

This is the code for calculating lat/lons from xy:

```
def calc_latlon(ds):
    
    x = ds.x
    y = ds.y
    goes_imager_projection = ds.goes_imager_projection
    
    x,y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
    
    r_eq = goes_imager_projection.attrs["semi_major_axis"]
    r_pol = goes_imager_projection.attrs["semi_minor_axis"]
    l_0 = goes_imager_projection.attrs["longitude_of_projection_origin"] * (np.pi/180)
    h_sat = goes_imager_projection.attrs["perspective_point_height"]
    H = r_eq + h_sat
    
    a = np.sin(x)**2 + (np.cos(x)**2 * (np.cos(y)**2 + (r_eq**2 / r_pol**2) * np.sin(y)**2))
    b = -2 * H * np.cos(x) * np.cos(y)
    c = H**2 - r_eq**2
    
    r_s = (-b - np.sqrt(b**2 - 4*a*c))/(2*a)
    
    s_x = r_s * np.cos(x) * np.cos(y)
    s_y = -r_s * np.sin(x)
    s_z = r_s * np.cos(x) * np.sin(y)
    
    lat = np.arctan((r_eq**2 / r_pol**2) * (s_z / np.sqrt((H-s_x)**2 +s_y**2))) * (180/np.pi)
    lon = (l_0 - np.arctan(s_y / (H-s_x))) * (180/np.pi)
    
    ds = ds.assign_coords({
        "lat":(["y","x"],lat),
        "lon":(["y","x"],lon)
    })
    ds.lat.attrs["units"] = "degrees_north"
    ds.lon.attrs["units"] = "degrees_east"
    return ds
```

[This is the metadata for the xr dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfwIA.png) in its current form, you can see xy is the reference system and lat/lon is just an appended coordinate. Broken down into an xarray data array [it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMXNI.png), but it keeps xy as the coordinate system despite having lat/lon available. That is my issue. So I need to be able to either change the way the original function formats the lat/lons or somehow separate the coordinate pairs and set it to the dataset index. Or maybe there is a way to set index using the coordinate pairs. I can't for the life of me figure out how to do either one.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow"). In order for us to help you, it is necessary that you show your effort and submit data to be used to reproduce your problem. While providing an image is helpful, it doesn't allow for reproducing the issue. Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details.

Answer (score 0):

For Though more complicated than I was hoping for, a bit of code is posted here that I was able to adapt and solve my problem. [Converting from 2D lat/lon matrix into 1D lat/lon array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71616481/converting-from-2d-lat-lon-matrix-into-1d-lat-lon-array?rq=1)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).